# Find all $f(x)$ if $f(1-x)=f(x)+1-2x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

To find one solution I assumed that $f$ is even and rewrote this as $f(x-1)-f(x)+2x=1.$ By just thinking about a solution, I was able to conclude that $f(x)=x^2$ is a solution. However, I am sure that there are more solutions but I don't know how to find them.

Comment: Is $f$ supposed to be continuous, differentiable, etc.?

Comment: There are no restrictions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HINT:

As $f(x)-x=f(1-x)-(1-x),$ put $f(x)-x=g(x)$

I'm tempted to add this :

(As IvanLoh has pointed out), if we need $f(x)$ in polynomials

As $f(x)-f(1-x)=2x-1$ which is $O(x^1), f(x)$ can be at most Quadratic

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

$\implies 2x-1=f(x)-f(1-x)=ax^2+bx+c-\{a(1-x)^2+b(1-x)+c\}$
$\implies 2x-1=-(a+b)+2(a+b)x^2$

Equating the constants $a+b=1$

and equating the  coefficients of $x,a+b=1\implies b=1-a$

So, any $f(x)=ax^2+(1-a)x+c$ will satisfy the given condition

Comment: Well can I do this? g(x)=g(1-x), so x=1-x, then x=1/2, so f(x)=f(1/2). I've never done this before, is it ok?

Comment: @Ovi, how $g(x)=g(1-x)\implies x=1-x?$

Comment: I was thinking to take the inverse of both sides but I just realized how stupid that is.

Comment: Ah yes that looks simpler (+1). It so happens that $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=x^2$ are both solutions, so both $f(x)=x+g(x)$ and $f(x)=x^2+g(x)$ will work.

Comment: @Ovi $g(x)$ can be any function which is symmetric about the line $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @IvanLoh: Yeah thanks I just realized that

Comment: @Ovi, To elaborate IvanLoh's statement, $g(x)=g(1-x), g(y+\frac12)=g(\frac12-y)$

Comment: But wait a second. There are an infinite amount of functions that are symmetric with respect to $x=1/2$, so there are an infinite amount of solutions for f(x). However, the question asks to list $all$ the solutions.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee That works for polynomial solutions. If one wants to characterize all solutions, we can just say: "All solutions are given by $f(x)=x+g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is any function symmetric about the line $x=\frac{1}{2}$."

Comment: @IvanLoh, more generally $f(x)=ax^2+(1-a)x+c+g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is any function symmetric about the line $x=\frac12$

Comment: It's actually the same characterization, since $ax^2-ax$ is also symmetric about the line $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Let $f(x)=x^2+g(x)$. What properties must $g(x)$ have?

Comment: could you please share how have you deduced  $f(x)=x^2+g(x)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The OP found $f(x)=x^2$ to be a solution, so $f(x)=x^2+g(x)$ would work.

Comment: got your point.Would mind having a look into my edited answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof which finds *all* $\;f\;$ for which this equality holds, as the OP (long ago) asked.$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
%$  We treat this as a problem to try and simplify the equality, and to try and reduce it to its essentials.

We calculate, for every $\;f \in \mathbb R \to \mathbb R\;$,
$$\calc
   \tag{0}
   \langle \forall x :: f(1-x) = f(x)+1-2x \rangle
\op{\tag{*}\equiv}\hint{arithmetic -- to introduce symmetry}
   \langle \forall x :: f(1-x)-(1-x) = f(x)-x \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{abbreviate $\;g(x) = f(x)-x\;$}
   \langle \forall x :: g(1-x) = g(x) \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{substitute $\;x := \tfrac 1 2 +x\;$ -- to introduce symmetry}
   \langle \forall x :: g(\tfrac 1 2 -x) = g(\tfrac 1 2 +x) \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{abbreviate $\;h(x) = g(x+ \tfrac 1 2)\;$}
   \langle \forall x :: h(-x) = h(x) \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{definition of even}
   h\text{ is even}
\endcalc$$

Therefore, if $\;h\;$ is an even function, then (and only then) $\;f(x) = g(x)+x = h(x-\tfrac 1 2)+x\;$ satisfies $\Ref{0}$.

One example of such an even function is $\;h(x) = ax^2 + c\;$, which gives $\;f(x) = ax^2 + (1-a)x + c + \tfrac a 4\;$, essentially [lab bhattacharjee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33337/lab-bhattacharjee)'s answer.  And $\;f(x) = \cos(x- \tfrac 1 2) + x\;$ is another valid answer.

Note how the very first step $\Ref{*}$ is really the most creative one, and the others are more or less forced by the desire to find symmetry.

$%
\endgroup
%$

Comment: I'm posting this for completeness, since the question was only really answered in [Ivan Loh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/61044/ivan-loh)'s comment on the currently accepted answer: "All solutions are given by $f(x)=x+g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is any function symmetric about the line $x=\tfrac 1 2$." [(link)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409062/find-all-fx-if-f1-x-fx1-2x#comment875648_409064) The trigger for posting this is that I found back the above calculation on a piece of paper I wanted to throw away. :-) I believe I came up with this without using the earlier answers.

Comment: +1 I very much enjoyed your explanation. Is finding symmetry usually good in solving any type of problem, or is it mostly useful in competition style problems or functional equations?

Comment: In my experience, introducing symmetry is very often a good strategy in mathematics, and not only for "competition style problems" (whatever that might be :-) ), and certainly not just for functional equations.  Here is a definition of mathematics I really like: "Mathematics is the classification and study of all possible patterns." [Walter Warwick Sawyer, Prelude to Mathematics, p.12](https://books.google.nl/books?id=6wF4SklxcnkC&pg=PA12&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)  And symmetry is a kind of pattern...  Note that also avoiding to _break_ symmetry is a good strategy.